# What is the formula of correlation coefficient against 3 or more variables?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression

This is the formula for calculating the coefficient of correlation between a single subject value ($z$) and two reference variables ($x$ and $y$).

[image]

The question is how to expand it to cases when there are 3 or more variables in the reference set.

Update: Adding some explanation as the notation was said to be unclear...

$x$, $y$, $z$ etc are variables (lines). $R$ is the correlation coefficient, $R$zx is the coefficient of correlation between $z$ and $x$ (defined in the definition 2 [here](http://www.real-statistics.com/correlation/basic-concepts-correlation/)). $R$z,xy is the coefficient of correlation of a dependent variable $z$ to two independent variables: $x$ and $y$ (defined in the definition 1 [here](http://www.real-statistics.com/correlation/multiple-correlation/) where it is also said that it "may also be expanded to more than two independent variables" but is not explained how).

Comment: I have tried to expand the formula myself logically but I am getting above-one results from it as the right sides (those subtracted) of both numerator and denominator get extremely small.